# Virtual page view funnel not showing the drop outs from any step

Tags: google-analytics

I am creating a destination goal for my funnel visualization.I have created virtual page views and used same in my funnel step inside goal.My Funnel report is ok if user completes a session , but its not showing drop outs from any step (not showing the exit).Please help.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Do you see your users completing all the steps, or they complete the goal by entering the funnel at the success page?

Comment: No, They are completing all the steps starting from mobile/NRIC page.

Comment: Its my testing environment, I am working on all the process and completing all the steps starting from mobile NRIC page.

Comment: What do you see, when you intentionally abandon the flow at a specific step, during your testing?

Comment: On redirecting to another link after filling form in between, i am expecting this should be treated as a drop out ans should be visible inside my funnel report as exit.

Comment: Do i need to change in my goal or it is ok?

Comment: The setup looks OK. What do you see in analytics, if you make a test, and abandon the flow. Do you still see yourself as completing the goal? Please note, that one goal can be completed only once per session. You should reset your Analytics client id during tests.

Comment: No, That time nothing happens in  my funnel report. How can i  reset my Analytics client id? Please let me know.

Comment: You can delete your _ga cookie, or open the site in a new incognite window, after closing earlier incognito window.

Comment: what if i use regular-expression in my URL? and destination URL like ^/update-profile as my destination URL is /update-profile?result=SUCCESS

Comment: IMHO it's not the root of the problem, as your current 'Begins with' setting is doing the same.

Comment: Then what could be the possible issue?I have wasted so much time on this issue, yet not able to find a proper solution.

Comment: My goal count is increasing even if i drop from in-between , but no change in conversion rate and  funnel.

Comment: Have you checked, e.g. in your All pages report, that the funnel steps are sent correctly, and you see them as pageviews?

Comment: Yes , i have checked page views are firing accordingly.

Comment: i have seen exit steps in funnel report  around 4 hours back, but suddenly everything disappeared and 0 is showing everywhere and funnel conversion rate s 100%.I don't understand how?

Comment: In Analytics free version it takes up to 48 hours to have all data processed.

Comment: no, Its google analytics 360 account.